# Obtener datos de una cadena en Python

Tags: python, array

Me pueden ayudar con el sig problema que tengo.

Tengo la sig cadena:

```
Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:802|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1,Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:850|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1,Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:1627|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1
```

Estoy intentando obtener los datos `"7558", "7558", "7558" y "802", "850", "1627"`
Este es mi codigo:

```
for y in str(nvaCadena):
        o_pro = nvaCadena.index('Pro:') + 4         
        f_pro = nvaCadena.index('|Nom:')            
        p = nvaCadena[o_pro: f_pro]

        o_nom = nvaCadena.index('|Nom:') + 5
        f_nom = nvaCadena.index('|Esq:')
        n = nvaCadena[o_nom:f_nom]
```

Pero obtengo lo sig:

```
7558 - 802
7558 - 802
7558 - 802
```

Cuando en realidad quiero obtener:

```
7558 - 802
7558 - 850
7558 - 1627
```

Podrían ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes acá es que el método `index` del tipo `str` siempre [devolverá el menor índice en el que una subcadena coincide en la cadena principal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) y hasta ahora en cada iteración del `for` estás buscando en la misma cadena. Necesitas modificar la cadena que analizas en cada iteración, removiendo los datos ya encontrados (teniendo en cuenta los índices encontrados y la longitud de las subcadenas extraídas). Debes tener en cuenta que el tipo `str` es inmutable, necesitarías entonces utilizar una cadena auxiliar, a la que puedas ir asignando un nuevo valor, y preferiblemente en un bucle `while`; todo esto puede requerir mucho código innecesario. También debes tener en cuenta que `index` levanta una excepción del tipo `ValueError` si la subcadena no se encuentra.

Sugiero que utilices una expresión regular para interpretar la cadena, junto a la función `findall` del módulo `re`, por ejemplo:

```
import re

patron = r'(?:Pro|Nom):(\d+)'
texto = 'Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:802|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1,Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:850|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1,Tip:1-Cli:337|Neg:695|Pro:7558|Nom:1627|Esq:1|Rub:None|Con:None|Emp:None|Com:1'

resultado = re.findall(pattern, texto)
print(resultado)
```

> ['7558', '802', '7558', '850', '7558', '1627']

Creo que con esto puedes llegar fácilmente al resultado que requieres. ¡Las expresiones regulares son bastante poderosas!

También podrías modificar el patrón para recibir valores de diferentes variables, e incluso para recibir el nombre de esas variables y no perderte con qué dato corresponde a qué; por ejemplo, acá transformo la cadena en algo que puede manipularse con mayor facilidad en Python:

```
patron = r'(Pro|Nom|Esq):(\d+)'
resultado = re.findall(pattern, texto)
print(resultado)
```

> [('Pro', '7558'), ('Nom', '802'), ('Esq', '1'), ('Pro', '7558'), ('Nom', '850'), ('Esq', '1'), ('Pro', '7558'), ('Nom', '1627'), ('Esq', '1')]